# Off-by-one error in string delimitation program in Java

Tags: java, string

The goal of the following program is to delimitate the source string thanks to the separators `"/"` `" "` and `":"`. The expected output is `20 03 2016 17 30` but it yields only `20 03 2016 17`, omitting the last element. Maybe some off-by-one error?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String source = "20/03/2016:17:30";
    String sep = "/:";
    String[] result = new String[5];
    String str = "";
    int index = 0;

    for (int sourcePos = 0; sourcePos < source.length(); sourcePos++) {
        int compt = 0;

        for (int sepPos = 0; sepPos < sep.length(); sepPos++) {
            if (source.charAt(sourcePos) == sep.charAt(sepPos)) compt++;
        }

        if (compt > 0) {
            result[index] = str;
            System.out.print(" " + result[index]);

            if (index < result.length)
                index++;
            else
                break;

            str = "";
        } else {
            str = str + source.charAt(sourcePos);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply use `regex`:

```
String[] result = source.split("/|:");
```

As for your code, the reason why you are off by one is that the main `for` loop is terminated before you reach `if (compt > 0)` for the last time. In other words, `sourcePos < source.length()` is `false`, before you can add the last `str`.

You could so something like:

```
for (int sourcePos = 0; sourcePos < source.length() ; sourcePos++) {
    boolean compt = false;

    for (int sepPos = 0; sepPos < sep.length(); sepPos++) {
        if (source.charAt(sourcePos) == sep.charAt(sepPos)) { 
            compt = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (compt) {
        result[index] = str;
        index++;
        str = "";
    } 

    else if(sourcePos == source.length()-1) {
        result[index] = str + source.charAt(sourcePos);
    }

    else {
        str = str + source.charAt(sourcePos);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to add this comment a bit late but it seems like there is another kind of off-by-one error with your code, as the output is  "20 /03 /2016 :16" instead of "20 03 2016 17 30". Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for a solution without regex (cite "...but I meant to do it without regex")

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String source = "20/03/2016:17:30";
    String result = "";
    String before = "";
    for (int sourcePos=0; sourcePos < source.length(); sourcePos ++ ) {
        if (java.lang.Character.isDigit(source.charAt(sourcePos))) {
            result += before + source.charAt(sourcePos);
            before = "";
        } else {
            before = " ";  // space will be added only once on next digit
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Anything other than a digit is considered a separator, even if it is more than one character.